# Why is Windows XP tag showing zero questions ?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags

I noticed this while retagging a question, a search for questions tagged `[windows-xp]` returns [12 questions](http://www.imagecross.com/11/image-hosting-view-38.php?id=5423windows-xp-search.PNG), so why is the tagging area indicating [that there are no questions](http://www.imagecross.com/11/image-hosting-view-38.php?id=5701tagged.PNG) tagged `[windows-xp]` ?

/ot: There are ONLY 12 questions tagged `[windows-xp]` o_0

Comment: ot: (slightly) offtopic @Juan

Comment: It wasn't me!  o.O

Comment: it was me... :(

Comment: Whatcha do  @quack

Comment: @quack Yeah, can you tell us what happened?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We had a little moderator ... accident ... and all the windows-xp tags were destroyed. It'll be a day or two before I have time to put together triage.

Ok, this is fixed. Luckily a space was left behind so I could use it to detect where the old [windows-xp] tag was supposed to go.

We'll improve the moderator tools to make this more .. difficult .. to do accidentally, in the future.

Comment: Er , accident ?

Comment: Might be related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53923/super-user-has-2895-question-with-a-blank-tag

Comment: @Jeff, let me introduce you to some expanded vocabulary to replace the word *accident:* Disaster. Calamity. Apocalypse. Act of God. Those are all excellent replacements for the word *accident*. Even better: Accidental disaster/calamity/apocalypse/(act of God)

Comment: "First shalt thou take out the Holy Pin, then shalt thou count to three, no more, no less. Three shall be the number thou shalt count, and the number of the counting shall be three. Four shalt thou not count, neither count thou two, excepting that thou then proceed to three. Five is right out."

Comment: my bad.  i counted to five.  thanks, jeff, for the quick response.